# "Did not find handler method for" log messages with Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When I include the `actuator` and enable `debug` logging messages then there are lots of `Did not find handler method for` log messages.

```
2015-08-14 18:34:25.335 DEBUG 94889 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /index.html
2015-08-14 18:34:25.336 DEBUG 94889 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/index.html]
```

When I remove the `actuator` then these log messages disappear.

I have tried with versions Spring Boot 1.2.5 and 1.3.0.M3 and it works the same. It is easy to try out by generating a project with `spring initializr` using `web` and `actuator` dependencies.

Do you know what could be the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever found out what was happening here? I'm having the exact same issue, but with a lot more endpoints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Actuator adds `EndpointHandlerMapping` to route requests to the various endpoints that it provides. When a request is received, Spring MVC asks each handler mapping in turn for the handler for the request, stopping as soon as one is provided. The log messages are produced when a request for `/index.html` is made. There's no endpoint mapped to that path so `EndpointHandlerMapping` returns `null` and Spring MVC moves on to the next mapping.

Comment: Would this answer indicate why we would see apparent error messages and yet the correct page be presented -- that is, there are errors and yet things seem to be working correctly?

Comment: @Jeff No, not if they really are error messages. This question and answer are about debug messages